# Handling single click and double click separately in QTableWidget

Tags: qt

I have a `QTableWidget` widget in my application. I have to handle both single-click and double click mouse events separately in my application. Right now, only single-click slot is being called even when I double click on a cell. How do I handle them separately?

The following is the code for the signal-slot connection:

```
connect(ui.tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int, int)), this, SLOT(myCellClicked(int, int)));
connect(ui.tableWidget, SIGNAL(itemDoubleClicked(QTableWidgetItem*)), this, SLOT(tableItemClicked(QTableWidgetItem*)));
```

Am I missing any other configuration here?

Comment: Maybe you click too slow? :D It's weird because this kind of situation is included in Qt sources

Comment: one solution I could think of is to find the time difference between the two clicks and call the single click slot if the difference is greater than some threshold. But this might differ on diff systems. Any other simple solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okey, now i see. I had similar problem few weeks ago. The problem is in your QTableWidgetItem. I don't know exactly how does it work, but sometimes you can miss your item and click on cell. That's how you can fix it. Connect it this way:

```
connect(ui.tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int, int)), this, SLOT(myCellClicked(int, int)));
connect(ui.tableWidget, SIGNAL(cellDoubleClicked(int,int)), this, SLOT(tableItemClicked(int,int)));
```

And in your tableItemClicked slot do it this way:

```
void MyWidget::tableItemClicked(int row, int column)
{
    QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
    item = myTable->item(row,column)
    /* do some stuff with item */
}
```