# Qt C++: Click and double click on QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview

How to get click AND double click event working on QTableVew?

I tried the folowing (in constructor of MyTableView, iheriting from QTableView):

```
connect(this, &QTableView::clicked, evtReceiver, &MyEventReceiver::onClick);
connect(this, &QTableView::doubleClicked, evtReceiver, &MyEventReceiver::onDoubleClick);
```

Then I get click events but no double click. If I remove the `connect` to the click event, then I can receive the double click. 
Then I tried to override

```
void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent * event)
```

**Problem 1**: I need to remove the `connect(this, &QTableView::clicked,...)` in order to get `mouseDoubleClickEvent` called, but then no click event anymore.

**Problem 2**: how to know which cell has been double clicked?

**Problem 3**: If I still want the click event, I can override `mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* evt)`, I thought... But then again, mouseDoubleClickEvent is not called anymore. And not talking about the problem 2...

Please note this is for Qt 5.8. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503313/handling-single-click-and-double-click-separately-in-qtablewidget), however it seems to be a Qt 4.8 solution only: there is no cellClicked signal anymore on QTableView in Qt 5!...

Comment: Souldn't it be `connect(tableViewPtr, &QTableView::doubleClicked, evtReceiver, &MyEventReceiver::onDoubleClick);` ?
You should probably give an example that at-least compiles.

Comment: cellClicked exists in Qt5, but cellClicked is a QTableWidget signal so you can not use it in QTableView, on the other hand I have tested what you point out and I see that it works correctly: that is, when I click the onClick slot is called, and if it makes a double -click is called onClick and onDoubleClick. So probably the error is in another side, so if you want help you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: This is my test code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/6a326f94687f00cc2098b450740f0120

Comment: @eyllanesc First, thanks for your test code. However when I run it, and double click, I get 2 calls to onClick event, and no call to doubleClick event. I run it on Windows (once again, Qt 5.8), under VS2013.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem of your version, I've tried it with Qt 5.11.2 in Linux and it works correctly.

Comment: _Maybe it's a problem of your version_ Yeah, but it could also be worth to check (and, may be, modify) [`QApplication::doubleClickInterval`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#doubleClickInterval-prop) before taking the effort of a Qt update. _The default value on X11 is 400 milliseconds. On Windows and Mac OS, the operating system's value is used._